# Can I use C headers in Delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, header, c++builder

Is it possible to compile C headers with the Rad Studio XE C++ compiler and link them with Delphi code?

Thus eliminating the need to convert header files to pascal ?

The reason for the question is..

C - Header definition:

```
DLLEXPORT int url_engine_version(char *version, size_t length);
```

Attempt at Delphi Definition

```
function url_engine_version(version: PByte; var length: cardinal): integer;
  cdecl; external 'corplib.dll';
```

Main app tried to call it using:

```
engVer: Pointer;
engLen: cardinal;

engLen := 64;
GetMem(engVer,engLen);
url_engine_version(engVer,engLen);
```

But Delphi AV's when it tries to call the routine.

Working C# definition - Chick works if I pass a StringBuilder predefinded as length 64

```
[DllImport("corplib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int url_engine_version(StringBuilder version, [Out] int length);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's really the Delphi code crashing, and not the DLL function crashing? The AV error message will tell you which module the offending code belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your actual question is:  No.  Sorry.

However, I think in this case the problem is quite simple...

Either the C Header you have reproduced here is wrong or the C# declaration is or you have just been very lucky to not have the C# code crash and burn as badly as the Delphi code.

The problem I think is that the C Header declares the *length* parameter as a SIZE_T, *NOT* a pointer to a SIZE_T.  i.e. it is an input parameter, not an output or in/out parameter.

You presumably use *length* to specify the size of buffer allocated for the pointer you pass in *version*.  I further presume that the function *returns* the number of actual bytes used for the data placed in the *version* buffer.

The Delphi version crashes, I believe, because by specifying *length* as *var*, you are passing *length* by reference,  i.e. the function receives not "64" but a pointer to the value "64", but it is using this pointer value, not the 64 value.

The C# code may be dodging the bullet by (also incorrectly, if the C Header itself is correct) declaring the parameter as *out*.  This may translate into something that, if not correct, is at least not as "damagingly incorrect" at runtime.

I think simply removing the "var" from the length parameter declaration should solve your problem:

```
function url_engine_version(aVersion: PByte; aLength: cardinal): integer; cdecl; external 'corplib.dll';
```

Comment: Perfect. You are spot on.  The C Header is correct, and the length is by value not reference. Removing the var fixed the problem.  About to fix the C# version also. THANKYOU VERY MUCH....

Comment: User should also confirm that his C compiler's `size_t` is the same size as Delphi's `Cardinal` (which is 4 bytes).

Comment: @Rob: size_t is a standard C/C++ defined type that corresponds to Cardinal (on Win32), ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_t

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with converting are differences in the type system. A good delphi header can't be derived from c.

For example c doesn't distinguish pointers to one element and pointers to arrays. It doesn't distinguish bools and ints. A `char*` can mean a zero terminated string, a pointer to bytes, a pointer to a single char, a char passed by reference,...

And in your example the delphi code passes the last parameter by reference(i.e. as pointer to UInt32) and the c code doesn't. But I don't understand why the C# code works.

Answer (score 0):

Project JEDI have done a lot of C header conversions for Delphi.  They have an excellent set of resources, tutorials etc. on their [website](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/api-howto.html).

They also have a tool that can automate this which was actually derived from original code by Bob Swart.

Comment: Thanks.. Will add the website to my collection.